# RefreshFilter not working in DHTMLX grid. When I Use Custom Combo Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I am using custom combo box for filtering the data in the grid. When i change the data in the grid
the filter is not getting refreshed with new data. I used `grid.refreshFilters();`. Still i face this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to their [docs](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3afiltering):

Grid will not preserve row changes (adding , deleting), which was done when grid was in filtered state. After resetting back to not-filtered state, grid will restore deleted rows and remove newly created ones. To work around this issue you can use next order of actions:

1. unfilter grid
2. add|delete row
3. reset filter back

   ```
   grid.filterBy(0, ''); // unfilter
   grid._f_rowsBuffer = null; // clear cache

   // Change grid data by adding / deleting rows here

   grid.filterByAll();  // reset filters back
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading data with parse? I used event onXLE to refresh filters after data are loaded.

```
grid.attachEvent('onXLE', function (grid_obj, count) {
        grid_obj.refreshFilters();
    });
```